# How will I get success in Postman?

Tags: api, postman, fiddler

Using Fiddler,
I'm able to get the used params and Filename. Same thing I want to run in Postman. How can I do tjhat?

Fiddler:
[image: API Details from Fiddler]

Please note that I'm getting 200 in Fiddler. In postman I'm getting 400.

See How I'm passing in Postman:
**Inside Postman -> Body -> row:**

**Inside Postman -> Body -> binary -> Select File:** I'm attaching the same file.

File name is: dummy.pdf
But in Fiddler name is coming `dummy.pdf2_6_2020.pdf`

Postman Response:

```
{
    "head": {
        "StatusValue": 400,
        "StatusText": "Failed"
    },
    "body": {
        "Error": [
            {
                "status_value": 0,
                "status_text": "Invalid File"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can probably use form data in postman for this purpose. I have highlighted it in snapshot. Give name and value as you have given in Fiddler. I hope this helps.[image: See red lines in snapshot.]